# Setting CLASSPATH for Clojure project

Tags: clojure, jvm, classpath, jvm-languages

I have a plain project structure:

```
Base Dir
   src ;; Pile of Clojure files
   lib ;; Jar files
```

To export the classpath:
$ export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:src:lib/*

Trying to run a Clojure file:
java -cp $CLASSPATH -jar lib/clojure.jar src/wizard-game.clj
But I got:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/contrib/trace_*init.class or clojure/contrib/trace.clj on classpath:
>
>   Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/contrib/trace*_init.class or clojure/contrib/trace.clj on classpath:

Ok, this is a classpath issue but what/where I'm doing wrong?

Is there a better way to try to run it?

**UPDATE:**
I tried this command:

> java -classpath $CLASSPATH clojure.main  src/wizard-game.clj

It runs ok now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the `java` man pages regarding the `-jar` option:

> When you use this option, the JAR file
>   is the source of all user classes, and
>   other user class path settings are
>   ignored.

So that's a bit of a bummer, but the good news is that you can get around this by using a different launching syntax ([referenced at clojure.org](http://clojure.org/repl_and_main)):

```
java -cp $CLASSPATH clojure.main src/wizard-game.clj
```

Alternatively, use a tool like [Leiningen](http://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) to manage your project's classpath and dependencies for you!

Comment: How to run a standalone Clojure file in Lein?

Comment: Not sure about the file but you can run namespaces (witch should be the same thing) with 'lein run namespace'.

Answer (score 3):

This is a response to your "How to run a standalone Clojure file in Lein?" you should look at into lein run. I'm not sure the current state but there was a standalone Lein plugin and now there is at least some (maybe all) of the functionality build into lein by default.

Try running a  `lein help run` at the command line for a quick introduction.

Standalone lein-run project. Documentation may be useful. Not 100% sure if it matches up with the built-in `lein run` but I know from my own usage at least some of it does.

https://github.com/sids/lein-run